# Moving files in Hadoop using the Java API?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I want to move files around in HDFS using the Java APIs.  I cannot figure out a way to do this.  The FileSystem class only seems to want to allow moving to and from the local file system.. but I want to keep them in HDFS and move them there.

Am I missing something basic?  The only way I can figure to do it is to read it from the input stream and write it back out... and then delete the old copy (yuck).

thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use [FileSystem.rename()](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#rename-org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path-org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path-):

> ```
> public abstract boolean rename(Path src, Path dst) throws IOException
> ```
>
> Renames Path `src` to Path `dst`. Can take place on local fs or remote DFS.
>
> **Parameters:**
>   `src` - path to be renamed
>   `dst` - new path after rename
>   **Returns:**
>   `true` if rename is successful
>   **Throws:**
>   [IOException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html?is-external=true) - on failure

Comment: `FileSystem.rename()` is an abstract method. So how will that work?

Comment: You have to get the FileSystem implementation that corresponds to the filesystem in use (e.g. HDFS). `FileSystem fs = myPath.getFileSystem(config); fs.rename(myPath, otherPath);`

Comment: This doesn't actually move the source to the dst, it just re-links it. If the src and dst are are different volumes, this will return `false` with no explanation or error: https://community.mapr.com/thread/7415

Comment: Hi @sean, did you have a solution for the 'false' issue?

Comment: I had to use the 'FileUtil.copy' API like the below answer from Raj R

Answer (score 6):

The java.nio.* approach may not work on HDFS always.  So found the following solution that works.

Move files from one directory to another using org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy API

```
val fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration())
        val conf = new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration()
        val srcFs = FileSystem.get(new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration())
        val dstFs = FileSystem.get(new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration())
        val dstPath = new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(DEST_FILE_DIR)

        for (file <- fileList) {
          // The 5th parameter indicates whether source should be deleted or not
          FileUtil.copy(srcFs, file, dstFs, dstPath, true, conf)
```

Comment: interesting looks handy in case of move files

Comment: also works for s3 filesystem

Answer (score 1):

I think the FileUtilts replaceFile would also solve the purpose. 
http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.html#replaceFile(java.io.File, java.io.File)

Answer (score 0):

```
hdfsDirectory="hdfs://srcPath"   
 val conf = new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration()
        val src:Path = new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(hdfsDirectory)
        val fs = FileSystem.get(src.toUri,conf)
        val srcPath: Path = new Path("hdfs://srcPath")
        val srcFs =FileSystem.get(srcPath.toUri,conf)
        val dstPath:Path =new Path("hdfs://targetPath/")
        val dstFs =FileSystem.get(dstPath.toUri,conf)
        val exists = fs.exists(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(hdfsDirectory))
        val status:Array[FileStatus] = fs.listStatus(new Path(hdfsDirectory))
        if (status.length>0) {
          status.foreach(x => {
            println("My files: " + x.getPath)
            FileUtil.copy(srcFs, x.getPath, dstFs, dstPath, true, conf)
            println("Files moved !!" +x.getPath)
          }
          )}
        else{
          println("No Files Found !!")
        }
```