# Hadoop Mapreduce, How do I rewrite a txt file inputted in the mapper with map reduce output?

Tags: algorithm, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, k-means

I am trying to create a map reduce program to perform the k-means algorithm. I know using map reduce isn't the best way to do iterative algorithms.
I have created the mapper and reducer classes.
In the mapper code I read an input file. When a map reduce has completed I want the results to be stored in the same input file. How do i make the output file overwrite the inputted file from the mapper? 
Also so I make the map reduce iterate until the values from the old input file and new input file converge i.e. the difference between the values is less than 0.1

My code is:

```
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.StringTokenizer;
 import java.util.*;
 import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
 import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
 import java.io.FileReader;
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.util.ArrayList;


public class kmeansMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, DoubleWritable, 
DoubleWritable> {
private final static String centroidFile = "centroid.txt";
private List<Double> centers = new ArrayList<Double>();

public void setup(Context context) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
        FileReader(centroidFile));
        String contentLine;
        while((contentLine = br.readLine())!=null){
            centers.add(Double.parseDouble(contentLine));
        }
}

public void map(Object key, Text input, Context context) throws IOException, 
InterruptedException {

        String[] fields = input.toString().split("  ");
        Double rating = Double.parseDouble(fields[2]);
        Double distance = centers.get(0) - rating;
        int position = 0;
        for(int i=1; i<centers.size(); i++){
            Double cDistance = Math.abs(centers.get(i) - rating);
            if(cDistance< distance){
                position = i;
                distance = cDistance;
            }
        }
        Double closestCenter = centers.get(position);
        context.write(new DoubleWritable(closestCenter),new 
DoubleWritable(rating)); //outputs closestcenter and rating value

        }
}
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import java.util.*;

public class kmeansReducer extends Reducer<DoubleWritable, DoubleWritable, 
DoubleWritable, Text> {

public void reduce(DoubleWritable key, Iterable<DoubleWritable> values, 
Context context)// get count // get total //get values in a string
          throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            Iterator<DoubleWritable> v = values.iterator();
            double total = 0;
            double count = 0;
            String value = ""; //value is the rating
            while (v.hasNext()){
              double i = v.next().get();
              value = value + " " + Double.toString(i);
              total = total + i;
              ++count;
            }
            double nCenter = total/count;
  context.write(new DoubleWritable(nCenter), new Text(value));
}
}
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class run
{

 public static void runJob(String[] input, String output) throws Exception {

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

  Job job = new Job(conf);
  Path toCache = new Path("input/centroid.txt"); 
  job.addCacheFile(toCache.toUri());
  job.setJarByClass(run.class);
  job.setMapperClass(kmeansMapper.class);
  job.setReducerClass(kmeansReducer.class);
  job.setMapOutputKeyClass(DoubleWritable.class);
  job.setMapOutputValueClass(DoubleWritable.class);

  job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
  Path outputPath = new Path(output);
  FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, StringUtils.join(input, ","));
  FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outputPath);
  outputPath.getFileSystem(conf).delete(outputPath,true);
  job.waitForCompletion(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   runJob(Arrays.copyOfRange(args, 0, args.length-1), args[args.length-1]);

}

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know you put the disclaimer.. but please switch to Spark or some other framework that can solve problems in-memory. Your life will be so much better.

If you really want to do this, just iteratively run the code in runJob and use a temporary file name for input. You can see [this question on moving files in hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507804/moving-files-in-hadoop-using-the-java-api) to achieve this. You'll need a FileSystem instance and a temp file for input:

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
Path tempInputPath = Paths.get('/user/th/kmeans/tmp_input';
```

Broadly speaking, after each iteration is finished, do

```
fs.delete(tempInputPath)
fs.rename(outputPath, tempInputPath)
```

Of course for the very first iteration you must set the input path to be the input paths provided when running the job. Subsequent iterations can use the tempInputPath, which will be the output of the previous iteration.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, how do I go about iterating the code in runjob?

Comment: You an just wrap the necessary parts of the code in runJob in a normal for loop.